# Set storage location JackRabbit

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I've been searching for a long time how to set the location of a file stored using JackRabbit.
In JackRabbit Oak I do that :

```
FileBlobStore   store = new FileBlobStore(repository);
    DocumentNodeStore   documentStore = new DocumentMK.Builder()
            .setBlobStore(store).getNodeStore();
    Repository repo = new Jcr(new Oak(documentStore)).createRepository();
```

But I need to use JackRabbit 2.0 so what is equivalent in JackRabbit 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

You basically have to define that FileBlobStore so called DataStore in your repository.xml.

```
<Repository>
  <DataStore .../>    <!-- optional, available since 1.4 -->
</Repository>
```

Comment: u think he wanted a programatic way.